# Rails, submitting array to postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, strong-parameters

I have a Rails API and I am trying to pass an array of numbers to my postgres db but I can't: I send an array with two values, and it accepts an array with only the first value.

I have 2 models, `Itinary` and `Event` where:

```
class Event 
  belongs_to: itinary
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :itinary

class Itinary
   has_many: events
```

I use Postgres and a React front end and Rails API with Postgres. I declared a column of type `array` with values if type `decimal`:

- Rails Postgres schema: I set `DECIMAL` as the type:

```
create_table "itinaries", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.decimal "start_gps", default: [], array: true
```

- Rails `EventsController`: nothing fancy, from the `Event` controller, the create method is: `Event.new(event_params)`, and the strong params method is also rather simple:

```
def event_params
   params.require(:event).permit( 
      ...,
      itinary_attributes: [...,  start_gps: [] ],
      ...
   )
end
```

I checked that `Event.first.itinary.start_gps.class` returns `Array`. I can seed with `Itinary.create!(..., start_gps:[45,1])` (the values are numbers).

- React form: the data are sent within a `FormData` from React where I believe I used the correct Rails naming convention:

```
const fdata = new FormData()
fdata.append("events[itinary_attributes][start]", itinary.start)
fdata.append("events[itinary_attributes][start_gps][]", itinary.start_gps)
...
```

so the header of my POST request contains:

```
event[itinary_attributes][start_gps][]: 45.1936513315257,0.6646728515625
```

On submit, I get almost the desired params but the values in the array are quoted:

```
 Parameters: 
{"event"=>{
   "itinary_attributes"=>{
       "date"=>"2020-08-16",
       "start"=>"Paris FRA",
       "start_gps"=>["48.85011347181819,2.3353889957070355"], << one value ?
       }
   }
}
```

so that I get only the first value when Postgres fires:

```
 Itinary Create (2.5ms)  
INSERT INTO "itinaries" ...
  ["start_gps", "{48.85011347181819}"], <<<<< ONLY FIRST
                   ^^
]
```

- If I set `t.string` or `t.text` as the data-type in the schema, Postgres fires:

```
Itinary Create (2.5ms) 
 ["start_gps", "{\"45.18978009667531,0.6811523437500001\"}"]]
```

so `Event.last.itinary.start_gps.length` returns 1, a concatenated value:

```
start_gps: Array(1)
=> "45.158800738352106,1.5051269531250002"
```

I even tried to submit an array of strings from React without success. Where to start? This is something very classical I believe. Looks like Rails or Postgres can't read the comma ',' that separates two values in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
const fdata = new FormData()
fdata.append("events[itinary_attributes][start]", itinary.start)
fdata.append("events[itinary_attributes][start_gps][]", itinary.start_gps[0])
fdata.append("events[itinary_attributes][start_gps][]", itinary.start_gps[1])
```

This should get you

```
{"event"=>{
  "itinary_attributes"=>{
    "date"=>"2020-08-16",
    "start"=>"Paris FRA",
    "start_gps"=>["48.85011347181819", "2.3353889957070355"] <-- Two values in an array
   }
```

Comment: This will create params in the form `"start_gps"=>[{"0"=>"47.2", "1"=>"0.45"}`, not permitted by the strong params `start_gps: []`, so I would need to declare these keys. However, there should be a way to use an array without knowing it's length, shouldn't it? I still don't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In case of any interest, one can solve this 'manually': to save an array of numbers into an array field, I split the received params. This is unsatisfactory as such a simple job demands so much gesticulation. I still don't see what's wrong.

One solution is to add in the controller:

```
if params[:event][:itinary_attributes][:start_gps]
      params[:event][:itinary_attributes][:start_gps] = params[:event][:itinary_attributes][:start_gps][0].split(',')
end

event_params = params.require(:event).permit( 
   ...,
   itinary_attributes: [...,:start, start_gps: [], end_gps: []],  
   ) 
Event.new(event_params)
...
```

Comment: I edited my answer after you commented. It should give you the parameter split.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are write, I can append into the array this way. In this case, I know in advance that I want only two entries in the array. But elsewhere in my app, I append an unknown number of values in an array, so I would need to iterate over a calculated length to append programmatically if I do this from the front-end, or split the params with the back-end. I still can't find anything on passing arrays.